# Toggle(Hide/Show) <tr> using jQuery on specific attibute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I want to hide the `<tr>` based on the value of the attribute named `status_id`. And I'm using jQuery datatable.

This is what I have tried, but not working.

This is my table, from which, I want to toggle the `<tr>` with attribute `status_id` in `<span>`

```
<button id="hide-tasks" class="hide-tasks" type="button">Toggle</button>
<table id='tbl_taskList'>
<tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
        <td style="padding-right: 5px;">
            <span data-title="New - Unclaimed / Unassigned" class="data-hover stat_195 clas clickTip  badge  stat-adjust btn-list fa fa-adjust" status_id="4" move-left="500">&nbsp;</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And this is the js for that,

```
$(document).on('click', '.hide-tasks', function (e) {
    var toggleVal = [1, 9, 10, 11, 12];
    var statusToggle = $(this).closest('tr').children('span').find('status_id');
    if (statusToggle === toggleVal) {
        statusToggle.toggle();
    }
 });
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly `status_id` is an attribute of the `span`, so your use of `find()` is incorrect.

Secondly, the `button` is not within the `table`, so `closest()` will not find anything as it goes up the DOM. You would need a combination of `next()` and `find()`. You will also need to loop through the `span` element found in each `tr` using `each()`

Finally note that creating your own non-standard attributes will mean that your HTML is invalid. To store custom data with an element use `data-*` attributes.

From there you can use `indexOf()` to discover if the `status-id` is in the array, and `toggle()` the required element as needed. Try this:

```js
var toggleValues = [1, 9, 10, 11, 12];

$(document).on('click', '.hide-tasks', function(e) {
  $(this).next('table').find('span').each(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    $el.closest('tr').toggle(toggleValues.indexOf($el.data('status-id')) == -1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="hide-tasks" class="hide-tasks" type="button">Toggle</button>
<table id='tbl_taskList'>
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td style="padding-right: 5px;">
        <span data-title="New - Unclaimed / Unassigned" class="data-hover stat_195 clas clickTip  badge  stat-adjust btn-list fa fa-adjust" data-status-id="1" move-left="500">1</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td style="padding-right: 5px;">
        <span data-title="New - Unclaimed / Unassigned" class="data-hover stat_195 clas clickTip  badge  stat-adjust btn-list fa fa-adjust" data-status-id="2" move-left="500">2</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td style="padding-right: 5px;">
        <span data-title="New - Unclaimed / Unassigned" class="data-hover stat_195 clas clickTip  badge  stat-adjust btn-list fa fa-adjust" data-status-id="9" move-left="500">9</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td style="padding-right: 5px;">
        <span data-title="New - Unclaimed / Unassigned" class="data-hover stat_195 clas clickTip  badge  stat-adjust btn-list fa fa-adjust" data-status-id="10" move-left="500">10</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td style="padding-right: 5px;">
        <span data-title="New - Unclaimed / Unassigned" class="data-hover stat_195 clas clickTip  badge  stat-adjust btn-list fa fa-adjust" data-status-id="15" move-left="500">15</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: Thank you, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1) Use `$(this).closest('tr').children('span').find('span').attr('status_id')` to get the status_id

2) as `toggleVal` is an array, you cant compare  `statusToggle` which is string - with `toggleVal` - so use `$.inArray`

```
$(document).on('click', '.hide-tasks', function (e) {
    var toggleVal = [1, 9, 10, 11, 12];
    var spanEle = $(this).closest('tr').children('span').find('span');
    var statusToggle = spanEle.attr('status_id');
    if($.inArray(statusToggle, toggleVal) !== -1) {
        spanEle.toggle();
    }
});
```

Comment: That is the superb answer. And thanks for it. but didn't working for me.

Comment: You're calling `toggle()` on a string...?

Comment: You have a syntax error, and the logic is still not quite right